# os.mkdir under if not working python

Tags: python, python-os

I have the below code, the `os.mkdir` is not working on mine. Compiling does not return any error, but running the code does not create folder.

```
def folder():
    timenow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
    folderpath = os.path.join(currentpath,"folder",str(timenow))
    if os.path.exists(folderpath) == False:
        os.mkdir(folderpath)
    return
```

Comment: Could you post the code so someone can read it?

Comment: What's `currentpath`?

Comment: current path is directory: C:\PythonScript

Comment: You don't compile under Python.  You meant "running does not return any [runtime] error"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
def folder():
    timenow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
    folderpath = os.path.join(currentpath, "folder", str(timenow))
    if not os.path.exists(folderpath):
        os.makedirs(folderpath)
        print 'Created:', folderpath

folder()
```

`makedirs` will create the required subdirectories, whereas `mkdir` can only create one directory. That said, you should've seen an exception.

Comment: Thanks for this!, Just wondering why makedir shows an exception now when it works fine yesterday for the same code.

Comment: No worries. It may have been that the subdirectories already existed and you were only creating the `timenow` dir on the end (which should work).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at it, with some minor error handling...

```
def folder():
    timenow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
    folderpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"folder",str(timenow))
    if not os.path.exists(folderpath):
        os.makedirs(folderpath)
        if os.path.exists(folderpath):
            return (True, folderpath)
    return (False, folderpath)

f = folder()

if f[0]:
    print '"%s" was successfully created!' % (f[1])
else:
    print '"%s" could not be created, does the folder already exist? Do you have appropriate permissions to create it?' % (f[1])
```

Comment: thanks for this but the first IF handles the one inside it dont you think?

Comment: If the folder does not exist, create it, then the second if is used to ensure the folder you just created was actually successfully created. Just because you said to create a folder doesn't mean there are not other variables on your system that might cause the folder creation you initiated to fail, like permission issues, full hdd, bad sectors, etc.